# Have the Community Wiki conversion thresholds changed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, community-wiki

[This question on Programmers'](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/35471/47) has converted to CW.

However, the question itself hasn't been edited - not even by the OP, and there are only 16 answers (at the time of this posting).

So why, or indeed how, has it converted to CW?

The only thing I can think of is that the number of answers threshold has been reduced from 30 to 15 (?).

Is this a network wide change or can it be altered on a site by site basis?

Comment: Since this does affect Programmers specifically, you might consider relaying this information in an announcement on your Meta site. Admittedly, this is likely to cause an uproar... but it would be better that people are informed than to leave it to people to discover it and start a riot themselves.

Comment: @Grace - good idea. I was hoping to get a little bit more information first, but some is better than none. Now [posted](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/941/47)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The threshold is 15 on SU and Programmers.

Comment: Is this a recent change on Programmers? And where is it documented (apart from here)? Having warning of the change would have been nice in case questions were raised on meta.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not against the change. Just that it came as a surprise.