# Shouldn't this Super User question automatically become CW?

Tags: support, community-wiki, superuser, meta-faq

The [FAQ on CW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) posts states one reason for a post to automatically become CW:

> The question generates more than 30 answers (15 on Super User). In this case, the question and all answers will enter community mode, as will any future answers.

Now, this SU question has 20 answers already.

> [Easiest way to find out if user has either Windows 7 or Vista (through telephone support)?](https://superuser.com/questions/401370/)

Shouldn't it be CW, or is the FAQ wrong?

Comment: Hmmm, that may not necessarily be accurate. They might have changed it back. After all, Jeff's [original post](http://meta.superuser.com/q/274/29070) said "for now" and [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74582/141525) says it applies to Programmers too.